# hide and show div on button press

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

I have a javascript function that hides and displays a div based on a click event.

its working well but every-time the div is displayed it expands the entire hero sections i.e hero images, **h1** text. So everything jumps as it expands

I need to show the hidden div, expand the card without making the background image and h1 tag in the same section to not expand and increase in size when the hidden div is displayed after clicking the button.

you can try it here on this link: https://micencostagebank.nl/index_september.php

just click on the stage button twice and you will see what I mean.

```js
function displayCheckBox() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myDIV");  
  if (x.style.display === "none") {
    x.style.display = "inline";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="myDIV">        
  <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
    <input class="btn btn-primary" type="radio" name="traineeship_type" id="10weeks" value="4">
    <label class="btn form-check-label" for="inlineRadio1">Beroeporiënterende stage</label>
  </div>

  <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
    <input class="btn btn-primary" type="radio" name="traineeship_type" id="20weeks" value="5">
    <label class=" btn form-check-label" for="inlineRadio2">Beroepsvoorbereidende stage</label>
  </div>       
</div>
```

Comment: So, what do you want it to do then?

Comment: I need to show the hidden div, expand the card without making the background image and h1 tag in the same section not expand and increase in size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use visibility instead of display , the room created for mydiv DOM will not clear and no more jerk will happen, i have tested in your site too .

```
not to show  : visibility: hidden;
to show      : visibility: visible;
```

if you dont want like above mention, then my suggestion is to make the text right to buttons, next to baan button and make position absolute  adjust left and top and reduce font as shown below.

[image: example]